# How to check if object is cycles light source?

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, materials, light

My first idea was to get the **surface type** of the material. If this is an **emission shader** it should be a light source, but I can't find something in the python documentation to get the surface input.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by getting the material and checking if there is a node called *Emission* in the node tree, like this:

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.object
nodes = obj.data.materials[0].node_tree.nodes
if "Emission" in nodes:
    print("yes")
```

Likewise, you could also check for a *EMISSION* node by using this instead:

```
for node in nodes:
    if node.type == "EMISSION":
        print("yes")
```

That way if the user had changed the name it would still catch it.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense to me! But can't believe that we need to iterate over the whole tree to find out whether the object is a light or not... :)

Comment: Well if it hasn't been renamed then you don't need to.

Comment: @BlendingJake Python will still iterate trough the list anyway...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905513/python-in-keyword-efficiency

Comment: worried about lag? I just ran a script that created a list with 1,000,000 numbers in it and then checked to find a number in it. It only took 0.11 seconds.

Comment: I'm not worried about it, but I think it's really expensive to find a light in a scene. :) You have to check all objects, their materials and if there are node groups you also have to iterate through that. Anyway - Thanks for your help @BlendingJake!

Comment: One way to save a little would be to iterate through the materials first then just look for that material on the objects. Otherwise you might be looking through the same material multiple times.

Comment: @BlendingJake That's a good idea! Will try that.